# React Native how to make a complete Comment function?

Tags: react-native

I am making a comment function ,and I met an issue ,which is I have no idea how to add a comment list ? In my case , I am just able to add one comment ... Which dosen't make sence for a comment function .. XD
[image]

I attach my code here ,could you please help to take a look ?
Thank you so much !!

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View,TextInput, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';



function TryMsgScreen(props) {
    const [commentBox,showCommentbox] = useState(false);
    const [commentValue,setCommentValue] =useState("");
    const[showComment,setShowComment] = useState(false);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <FontAwesome name="commenting" size={34} color="black" onPress={()=>showCommentbox(true)}/>

        {/**Comment Container */}
         {commentBox&&(
              <View style={styles.comment_container}>
              <TextInput style={styles.input_txt} 
                         onChangeText = {(text)=>setCommentValue(text)}
                         placeholder = "type something ..."
                         />
            <Button title="send" onPress ={()=>{
                                               setShowComment(true);
                                               showCommentbox(false);
                                               }}/>
          </View>  
         )}
             

             {/**Show comments */}
             {showComment&&(
             <View style={styles.showComment_container}>
              <Text>{commentValue}</Text>
             </View>
             )}
             
        </View>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex : 1,
        flexDirection : 'column',
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems :'center',
    },
    comment_container : {
        width : "100%",
        minHeight : 50,
        flexDirection : "row",
        marginTop : 30,
        marginBottom :40,
    },
    input_txt : {
        width : "70%",
        borderWidth : 1,
        borderColor : "#000000",
        padding : 10,

    },
    showComment_container : {
        width : "70%",
        minHeight : 50,
        backgroundColor : "#B0C4DE",
        marginTop : 10,
        
    }
})
export default TryMsgScreen;
```

Comment: Create an array called `comments` and push items inside it by using a function.

Comment: Hey Kartikey ,Thank you so much for your tip . Hmm ,I had tried ,but still not working ..I am not sure if I am doing it good or not .. Could you please modify my code ,which will help me much more !! Thank you again !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/comments-implementation).

It has the implementation.

Your `TryMsgScreen` should look like this

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';

function TryMsgScreen() {
  const [Comments, SetComments] = useState([]);
  const [commentValue, setCommentValue] = useState('');
  const [showComment, setShowComment] = useState(false);
  const InputRef = useRef();

  // Function to add comments to array
  const AddToComments = () => {
    let temp = {
      id: GenerateUniqueID(),
      commentValue: commentValue,
    };
    SetComments([...Comments, temp]); // Adds comment to Array
    InputRef.current.clear(); // This clears the TextInput Field
  };

  // Function to Generate a Unique ID for array elements
  const GenerateUniqueID = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Date.now()).toString();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FontAwesome name="commenting" size={34} color="black" />

      <View style={styles.comment_container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input_txt}
          onChangeText={(text) => setCommentValue(text)}
          placeholder="type something ..."
          ref={InputRef}
        />
        <Button title="send" onPress={() => AddToComments()} />
      </View>

      {Comments.map((c) => (
        <View style={styles.showComment_container} key={c.id}>
          <Text>{c.commentValue}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

export default TryMsgScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  comment_container: {
    width: '100%',
    minHeight: 50,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
  input_txt: {
    width: '70%',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    padding: 10,
  },
  showComment_container: {
    width: '70%',
    minHeight: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#B0C4DE',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: Hey Kartikey ,Thank you sooo much for your kindness !!! It works now ,you have saved me my friend !

Comment: You are more than welcome, I'm glad I was able to help.